# Selecting multiple random rows in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am using handsontable in my project. Selection of continous rows i.e using shift key to select multiple continous rows is working fine, but when i am trying to select random rows using control key it is not working. I have been told that there is no way to select multiple random rows in handsontable.

We are initializing handson constructor in the following way :-

```
$element.handsontable({
                    columns:$scope.handsontable.columns,
                    data: $scope.handsontable.data,
                    colHeaders: $scope.handsontable.columnHeaders,
                    colWidths:$scope.handsontable.columnWidths,
                    readOnly:$scope.handsontable.readOnly,
                    fillHandle: false,
                    **currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
                    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',**
                    variableRowHeights : false,

                    cells: function () {
                        this.renderer = $scope.gridConfiguration;
                    }
               });
```

.css class for handson "currentRowClassName" and "currentColClassName" are provided as :-

```
.handsontable .currentRow {
  background-color: #66A3FF !important;
}

.handsontable .currentCol {
  background-color: #F9F9FB;
}
```

When looking into handsontable.js i found the following if block :-

```
if (priv.settings.currentRowClassName || priv.settings.currentColClassName) {
            instance.view.wt.selections.highlight.clear();
            instance.view.wt.selections.highlight.add(priv.selRange.from);
            instance.view.wt.selections.highlight.add(priv.selRange.to);
}
```

i tried commenting out its first line( `instance.view.wt.selections.highlight.clear();`) so that the selection does not get cleared but even this not working.

Please help me with selection of random(not necessarily continuous) rows using handsontable. Thanks

and tried changing it but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think HOT supports this sort of selection but you may be able to use some DOM manipulations to achieve it. What you can try is creating a `.beforeMouseDown` event where if the ctrl key and nothing else is selected, you append to some array the cell that you are currently on.

Then look through the source code to where this same thing is done for Shift. My guess is that it says that when Shift is held down, set `SelectedCells` to all cells between start and end of the selections. You just need to change it to ONLY start and end, not things in between.